# Docusign Admin API and ISV questions

Tags: docusignapi

We are from MCAS Team from Microsoft, India. We have specific Docusign Integration use case which needs your expert suggestion.

**MCAS(Microsoft Cloud App Security Team) one liner** – MCAS is a single/ common platform provided to Microsoft customers for monitoring all their cloud applications used in their organization helping the customer admin to monitor & track malicious/ unusual user behavior and configure necessary alerts & actions.

**MCAS Documentation for more details :** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-app-security/

**Our Use case:** Integrate the Docusign API - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/admin-api/reference/users/users/getusers/

and

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/monitor-api/reference/monitor/dataset/getstream/

**Queries:**

1. How to avoid the DocuSign App integration key Go-Live process for every MCAS customer(tenant)?
2. How to get a common higher rate limit benchmark for all the Microsoft MCAS customer(tenant) without explicit action by every MCAS tenant
3. How to get the Events of a organization in Global App Context. As on date, Events API is Integration key level but how to get events at Organization level
4. How to get the users of an organization. Current Admin API only supports by passing either of AccountId (API Account Id) or Reserve Domain Id or User emailid
5. User Profile Admin API expects email Id as input. This is returning array of users. How to get the User by User Id?
6. User roles are not returned in getUsers Admin API. Why?
7. Any API which would get the to get the user details by Id?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Every IK (Integration Key) must be [approved to go live](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/go-live/) so that it can be used in production, but you can use the same IK for multiple things if they are related (back-end and front-end of app for example).
2. Work with your DocuSign rep (support/sales) to help increase your rate limit if there's a legit need to do so.
3. See how to get Monitoring Events using the [DocuSign Monitor API](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/monitor-api/).
4. [The DocuSign Admin API](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/admin-api/reference/usermanagement/users/getusers/) can be used to get all the users in an
   organization.
5. [REST eSignature API](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/users/users/get/) can be used to get a user by userID (GET
   /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/users/{userId})
6. User groups and permission profiles are returned by Admin API or eSignature API. Roles are related to templates, so the terminology may be the issue here.
7. For users of eSignature you can use https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/users/users/get/